# another overflow-x: hidden vs overflow-y:visible issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a tab overflow UI similar to what firefox does, using a combination of fixed width containers and a fluid width container in the middle that holds the tabs.

The tricky part is when there are too many tabs in the tab container.  i've added `overflow-x:hidden; white-space:nowrap` to keep everything inside the container and on one line.  The tabs have context menus within them, so i need to display those as well when i click on a tab.  (the js has been omitted intentionally,as i'm just trying to get around this display issue which is css).

here's a fiddle that shows what i'm trying to accomplish.  http://jsfiddle.net/Add9Y/3/.

If you remove the comments on the overflow in the css on lines 5 and 13, you'll be able to see the submenu below the first tab, but now the overflow runs over the controls on the right hand side.

Any idea how i can get these to line up without having to rely on javascript?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, there was just an article on this exact issue:

http://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Here is the updated JSFiddle with this solution applied:

http://jsfiddle.net/Add9Y/4/

Updated part of the CSS:

```
.list > div {
    display:inline-block;
    //overflow-y:visible;
    line-height:48px;
    padding:0 5px;
    border:1px solid #bada55;
    //position:relative;
}
```

This appeared to work when I tested it (via Chrome), but I did not test too extensively.